# ¿Cómo puedo limitar la salida de entradas sugeridas en un input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

He terminado de crear un campo de búsqueda (ubicado arriba a la derecha en el panel de navegación) pero querría configurarlo de forma que:

- En caso de coincidir más de una cadena, solo permita aparecer 5 cadenas en los resultados.
- Hacer funcionar las coincidencias no solo en el inicio de la cadena sino en la cadena completa. De forma que si se busca "Pro" y "ducto" sean ambas formas válidas para llegar a la cadena completa "Producto".

¿Existe alguna forma de aplicar estas limitaciones? Actualmente este es el estado del proyecto: https://codepen.io/diegomanzanares/pen/mdxKNyd

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y coloca el código _en la pregunta_. [es.so] te da las herramientas adecuadas para ello. Piénsalo: si el enlace llega a romperse, se perderá parte fundamental del enunciado, y futuros lectores con un problema similar no podrán beneficiarse de tu pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba a cambiar la porción de código siguiente

```
const suggestions = searches.filter(function(country) {
    return country.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(input);
});
```

Por esta otra

```
encontrados = 0;
for(var i=0; i<searches.length && encontrados<5; i++){
    if(searches[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) != -1){
        suggestions.push(searches[i]);
        encontrados++;
    }
}
```

Lo que hago es recorrer el array **suggestions** y comprobar con el método **indexOf** si el string **input** se encuentra en el elemento iterado.

Con la condición **&& encontrados<5** en el for limito la búsqueda a 5 elementos

Comment: pero con eso limitas el total de cadenas que pueden salir. Es decir, me limita la salida de coincidencias a 5, pero también corta la lista en 5 y aunque sigas escribiendo no lo encuentra porque la lista ha terminado en el 5º elemento de la lista. Lo que quiero es que una vez analizada la cadena, muestre como máximo 5 resultados, no que muestre los 5 primeros de toda la lista.

Comment: ¿Pero qué criterio se ha de aplicar para elegir esas 5?. Como no especificaste ninguno he supuesto que eran las 5 primeras.

Comment: dentro de las entradas disponibles en la lista, lo que se busca es que coincidan con la búsqueda del usuario en la entrada de texto que tiene.

En otro ejemplo, si en la entrada están las cadenas manzana, manzanas, manzanero, manzanares, naranja, naranjero y limitamos a 4 el numero de resultados que pueden salir como resultado, si el usuario busca la cadena "manzan" deberían aparecer manzana, manzanas, manzanero y manzanares como resultados, pero naranja y naranjero deben seguir disponibles por si un usuario distinto busca por ejemplo la cadena "naranj" aparezcan en ese caso los 2 resultados

Comment: Perdóname Diego, pero no entiendo tu pregunta. Siguiendo tu ejemplo, si alguien busca el término "manzan", aparecerán "manzana, manzanas, manzanero y manzanares", tanto en mi versión como en la tuya. La diferencia en mi versión es que si el término buscado es "nzan", también aparecerán esos elementos y en tu versión no.

Lo que no entiendo es qué quieres decir con que "naranja y naranjero deben seguir disponibles", a qué te refieres con que "deben seguir disponibles".

Comment: lo que me refiero es que ahora mismo tengo una lista de 10 entradas en js, pero con ese código solo puedo buscar entre las 5 primeras entradas y es así como solo saca 5 valores. Pero a mi me interesa que primero filtre por la cadena y luego limite la salida a 5 valores en caso de que cumplan la condición.

He actualizado el código en el siguiente enlace, como puedes ver si buscas "nvidia", solo aparecen las 5 primeras entradas de la lista que cumplen la cadena, pero las cadenas que empiezan por intel las ignora cuando no debería: https://codepen.io/diegomanzanares/pen/GRxBqaK

Comment: Perdona Diego, fue error mío. Ya he corregido la respuesta arriba. Ahora creo que te debería funcionar bien.

Comment: ahora esa parte funciona correctamente, pero sigue buscando como no debe. Si ahora mismo busco la cadena "nvidia" aparecen todos los resultados relacionados (limitados a 5 caracteres, como hemos configurado antes y como es esperado que funcione), pero si busco la cadena "Nvidia" no aparecen resultados, como si de alguna forma fuese key sensitive. ¿Podría cambiarlo de alguna forma? Adjunto de nuevo el codepen actualizado:

https://codepen.io/diegomanzanares/pen/ExEpNzN

Comment: Para hacerlo "case insensitive", simplemente convierte también el input a "lower case". Ya te lo he puesto en el ejemplo.

Comment: ahora si funciona al completo. Infinitas gracias por tu ayuda.